# Error al pintar los datos en una tabla por medio de una petición con la API fetch

Tags: javascript, ajax, fetch

Tengo el siguiente código con el cual hago una petición tipo AJAX a la API de Github; lo cual logro sin problemas

Sin embargo al momento de pintar los datos en una tabla la que debería ser una columna con los datos tipo login, se sigue de largo a la derecha y no logro comprender como hacer que funcione; es decir que los datos se acomoden de manera horizontal en forma de columna

ADJUNTO MI CÓDIGO

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <button id="carga">Hola</button>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>Login</th>
      <th>Type</th>
    </tr>
    <tr id="data">

    </tr>
  </table>
<script>
    window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
       btn = document.querySelector('#carga').onclick = carga
    })

    async function carga(){
      layout = document.querySelector('#data')
      const response = await fetch('https://api.github.com/users')
      let data = await response.json()
      data.map(r => {
        layout.innerHTML += `<td>${r.login}</td>`
      })
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Crea cada fila dentro del bucle, de lo contrario no saltará en cada usuario.

Además haz el `inner` una sola vez, fuera del bucle, dentro recoge cada fila en una variable solamente. Cada vez que haces inner dentro modificas el DOM y eso no es recomendable desde el punto de vista de la optimización.

Propongo esta solución:

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  btn = document.querySelector('#carga').onclick = carga
})

async function carga() {
  layout = document.querySelector('#data')
  const response = await fetch('https://api.github.com/users')
  let data = await response.json()
  //console.log(data);
  var theRows="";
  data.map(r => {
    theRows += `<tr><td>${r.login}</td><td>${r.type}</td></tr>`
  })
  layout.innerHTML=theRows;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bulma/0.7.1/css/bulma.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body>
  <button id="carga">Hola</button>
  <table class="table is-striped">
      <th>Login</th>
      <th>Type</th>
    <tbody id="data">
    </tbody>

  </table>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: muchas gracias @A.Cedano comprendido y anotado :-)